# Creating DB Schema from sqlite in sqlite manager

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, information-schema

I have a sqlite database in sqlite manager. I would like to create DB schema. How can i do that? Or is it best to use some software to create the DB Schema?

Need some suggestions and guidance.

Comment: DBSchema is a tool to be used for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a system table called sqlite_master. It contains the SQL CREATE statements for all objects.

So, all you need to do is to select all rows from this table, and run the sql statements.

You can also use Database->Export Database Structure, which will effectiveley do the same thing

Comment: it saves the file with an extension sql. I want to look at it. How do i do that?

Comment: is it a joke? Just open it with a notepad

Comment: this is not i want... i want a graphical form of the database where it shows the relationships between the tables

Comment: OK, we misunderstood you. You want a picture. You can use Visio for that. It draws nice pictures. Just connect to your sqlite database using an ODBC connector and Visio will do its magic

Comment: I am using mac.. download visio for mac?

Comment: can i use jdbc instead of odbc?

Comment: u can use firefox plugin SQLite Manager , if you have firefox browser

Comment: I am using the plugin already.. all i need is visio then right?

Answer (score 1):

there is only one database in SQLite for file.

probably you can create a new file and open that with sqlite manager.

Comment: no.. i want to get the schema from the manager itself. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

certainly you can
go to Database menu + create new Database

http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/wiki/CommonTasks

Comment: if you are talking about this http://www.sqlabs.net/sqlitemanager.php then the option of crating a new database in the startup wizard itself